# Matplotlib - Basemap Installation Error

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

Installed basemap via pip 
`pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git`

```
from mpl_tooklits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get the error `module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'pyproj_datadir'`
found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujVPE.jpg

Any advice on how to resolve this? I tried going into the pyproj folder and change the **init**.py from `pyproj_datadir` to just `datadir`. That led to more errors, so I reversed that. I'd like to not change the source files too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the same installation procedure, I had the same problem.

Downgrading `pyproj` from version 2.1.3 to 1.9.3 solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yup, or `1.9.2` works